# WebView load HTML page with all resources from a local directory

Tags: xcode, cocoa, webview, macos

I am developing a COCOA application. It's a requirement of the application to load HTML page from a local directory. The HTML page includes links to many resources such as images, JavaScript, XML and CSS file. Hence it's more like a local website without any server. How can I achieve this using WebView control? I am developing application for Mac OS X.

Any help would be highly appreciated,
Farooq-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this code -

```
[[yourWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathOfLocalWebPage]]];
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
let urlpath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html");
let requesturl = URL(string: urlpath!)
let request = URLRequest(url: requesturl!)
webView.mainFrame.load(request)
```