# OSX Swift webview load local file

Tags: macos, swift, webview, local

I know this has been asked many times and I have read [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716221/ios-uiwebview-load-local-device-html-file-path?lq=1) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283654/webview-load-html-page-with-all-resources-from-a-local-directory) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063276/how-to-load-local-html-file-into-uiwebview) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959243/nsurlconnection-nsurlrequest-proxy-for-asynchronous-web-service-calls)
and googled for days with no success so far.

I just want to load a local html file in a desktop app, truth is for this project I need a JS library and most of it is already done as a webpage (css, js and html, no server side processing needed). I dont want to force the app to load the webpage from an internet server so as to not force the users to have an internet connection. Needless to say I am completely inexperienced in Swift and apple development.

Right now this is the problem I am having:
[image]
the ide complaints about the params and I cant seem to get them right.

For reference here is a snippet of my latest code:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!
    typealias NSSize = CGSize

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?)
    {
        self.window.title = "Chess Study Room"

        var try1 = "main.html";
        println(try1);

        var try2 = NSURL(string: try1)!;
        println(try2);

        var try3 =
        NSBundle.URLForResource("main", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "web", inBundleWithURL: try2);
        println(try3);

        var try4 = NSBundle.pathForResource("main", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "web");
        println(try4);

        var try5 = NSString.stringByAppendingPathComponent("main.html");
        println(try5);
        // var myInternalUrl = NSURL(string: myInternalHtml)!;
        //NSLog("%s", myInternalHtml!);
        var request = NSURLRequest(try1,
            NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
            60
        );

        self.webView.frameLoadDelegate = self;
        self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(
            request!
        );
    }
```

But as you can see from my gif I've tried other things as well. The full errors are `/path/TestWebView/AppDelegate.swift:32:35: Extra argument in call` and `/path/TestWebView/AppDelegate.swift:32:36: Missing argument for parameter 'cachePolicy' in call`

At this point try1 and try2 output "main.html", try3 and try4 output nil and try5 outputs"(Function)"

The structure of folders is this:
[image]

I added the folder "web" as a reference (as advised in another question) but I doubt this would work to ship just one package...

I dont know if there's any difference but I'm not targetting iOS, I want this to be a desktop app.

Any advise will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading [this post in the apple forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1050019#1050019) and putting it together with [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176362/nsurlconnection-using-ios-swift) I was able to come up with the following working code:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?)
    {
        self.window.title = "My App Title"

        var try6 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("main", ofType:"html")!)

        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: try6!);

        self.webView.frameLoadDelegate = self;
        self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(request);
    }
```

Comment: Path is not relative. It works but breaks all the relative files that html calls.

Comment: @EdiBudimilic Not in my case, it didn't break any of my relative paths.